# Inequality involving $f(x)=x^p$ with $0<p<1$

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f(x)=x^p$ with $0<p<1,p\in \Bbb{R}$ defined in $[0,+\infty[$. Knowing that $f$ is crescent, show that, $\forall a,b\in \Bbb{R}$,  $$(|a|+|b|)^p\leq|a|^p+|b|^p$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, let's assume $a,b\geq 0$ and consider instead
$$
(a+b)^p\leq a^p+b^p.\tag{A}
$$
If $a=b=0$, there is nothing to prove so we can assume that $a+b>0.$ In this case, (A) is equivalent to
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^p+\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^p\geq 1.\tag{B}
$$
But because $0<p<1$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^p\geq\frac{a}{a+b}\quad\text{and}\quad\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^p\geq\frac{b}{a+b}.
$$
From these, (B) follows immediately.

**p.s.** One way to see $\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^p\geq\frac{a}{a+b}$ is via the concavity of $f(x)=x^p$:
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^p=f\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\times 1+\frac{b}{a+b}\times 0\right)\geq\frac{a}{a+b}f(1)+\frac{b}{a+b}f(0)=\frac{a}{a+b}.
$$